# Retrieve file list passed by ajax call to a php controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

i have passed two strings and one list to a controller using an ajax call.From controller i can retrieve my string values. but the list that i passed come as an object. how to convert that object to a list.

this is my ajax

```
var imagelist = [];
if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
        alert("Add one or more images");
        ss
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {

            imagelist.push(x.files[i]);

        }
    }
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: url_path,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'pname': pname,
            'des': des,
            'ilist': imagelist
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("test");
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

controller is

```
 $images = $this->input->post('ilist');

    foreach($images as $img){


    }
```

this is the value that $images get

```
 [object File]
```

Comment: Try $images = json_decode($this->input->post('ilist'), TRUE); to fetch the list as an array.

Comment: It returns nothing.

Comment: If you do console.log in javascript. What does it show?

Comment: console.log(imagelist)  shows [File, File]  because i selected two images

Comment: Are you trying to upload files, or just send the file names?

Comment: yes im trying to upload files.

Comment: Whats the solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try sending the images with formdata object

Comment: Hi. If a question has a duplicate, then the question should rather be closed as a duplicate instead of being answered again. Also, an answer should contain a proper code example, not just "try using this or that". Show _how_ they could use "this" or "that" to solve the issue.